# Rasa NLU installation issue - Incompatible Version

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

I am trying to install rasa NLU using 'pip install rasa' command. The installation ends up with the compatibility error.

Kindly some one into the issue and help me out in resolving the version incompatible issue.

**Error:**

> C:\Users\Desktop\RASA NLU>pip install rasa
>
> Requirement already satisfied: h5py in
>   c:\users\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
>   keras-applications>=1.0.6->tensorflow~=1.13.0->rasa) (2.9.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in
>   c:\users\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\ site-packages (from
>   cryptography->python-telegram-bot~=11.0->rasa) (0.24.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in
>   c:\users\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
>   flask~=1.0->rasa-sdk~=1.0.0rc4->rasa) (7.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c
>   :\users\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3 \lib\site- packages (from
>   flask~=1.0->rasa-sdk~=1.0.0rc4->rasa) (1.1.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in
>   c:\users\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
>   flask~=1.0->rasa-sdk~=1.0.0rc4->rasa) (2.10.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in
>   c:\users\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
>   cffi>=1.11.5->gevent~=1.4->rasa) (2.19)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: docutils<0.16,>=0.10 in
>   c:\users\appdata\local\continuum \anaconda3 \lib\site-packages (from
>   botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.146->boto3~=1.9->rasa) (0.14)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in
>   c:\users\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
>   Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask~=1.0->rasa-sdk~=1.0.0rc4->rasa) (1.1.1)
>
> **ERROR: mxnet 1.3.1 has requirement numpy<1.15.0,>=1.8.2, but you'll have numpy 1.17.4 which is incompatible.
>
> ERROR: mxnet 1.3.1 has requirement requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4, but
>   you'll have requests 2.22.0 which is incompatible.
>
> ERROR: rasa-x 0.22.1 has requirement rasa~=1.4.0, but you'll have rasa
>   1.0.9 which is incompatible.
>
> ERROR: rasa-x 0.22.1 has requirement sanic~=19.6, but you'll have
>   sanic 19.3.1 which is incompatible.
>
> ERROR: apixu 0.3.0 has requirement requests==2.21, but you'll have
>   requests 2.22.0 which is incompatible.**
>
> Installing collected packages: requests   Found existing installation:
>   requests 2.21.0
>        Uninstalling requests-2.21.0:
>
> Successfully uninstalled requests-2.21.0 Successfully installed
>   requests-2.22.0

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check your python version it's must be > 3.5
Then Please try your installation with **--extra-index-url** params

***For Installation***

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --extra-index-url rasa
```

***For Upgrade to latest version***

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --extra-index-url rasa --upgrade
```

Still you can comment here for other errors.